# reactjs data.length accessible on save but not when browser refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I don't get it, in console I see my api data(array of 10 objects) but if I access the "data.data.length" when I save the file, it works(show number: 10 in console) but when I refresh the browser, the error occur(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined).

Also I found out that when my page refresh, it console.log "undefined" first then my array of 10 objects api data.....

I am so lost, what am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(
                'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=cat&limit=10&api_key=1234567890'
            )
            .then(({ data }) => {
                setData(data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
      {console.log(data.data)}
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What do you mean save the file? Also, first time your data will be an empty object. After componendidmount, it will have some data.

Comment: yeah but it shouldn't be undefined, it should be empty {}, so now it's undefined then array of objects but I thought it supposed to be empty {} then array of objects... cause my initial value for data is empty object.

Comment: data.data is undefined. data is your empty object. You mentioned you are accessing data.data.length in your question, although your code doesnt show it.

Comment: ah~~ I think I kind get it now, so when first load my data is empty object and I am trying to access data property inside of an empty object which it gives me undefined...

Comment: Spot on. Yes. You can check for the property and then access/ Something like : `if(data.data!== undefined) data.data.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the beginning of your component execution you have

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});
```

this is the first data you are using and this data is an empty object thats why data.data is undefined

Then your **effect** is executed and only after that data is updated in success case and remains the same in error(catch) state

So in case you want to use next code

```
data.data.length
// you are calling something like
// data.undefined.length
```

which in your case is throws exactly what it suppose to throw - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I would suggest you to use next piece of code if you like to use length

```
const length = data?.data?.length;
```

read more here
[Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

As the second option you can set starting state as

```
const [data, setData] = useState({data:[]})
```